# How to store an array of string in c#?

Tags: mongodb

Either

```
HashSet<string> aaa { get; set; }
```

or

```
List<string> aaa { get; set; }
```

or

```
string[] aaa { get; set; }
```

also store as:

```
"aaa": {
     "0": "bbb",
     "1": "ccc" 
},
```

can't store as

```
"aaa": ["bbb", "ccc"]
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code with the latest 10gen drivers produces the document in the format you're looking for:

```
public class MyDocument
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string[] aaa { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var db = server.GetDatabase("temp");
        var coll = db.GetCollection("myDocuments");
        var mydoc = new MyDocument
            {
                id = 1,
                aaa = new[] {"bbb", "ccc"}
            };
        coll.Save(mydoc);
    }
}
```

Here is the resulting document:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "aaa" : [ 
        "bbb", 
        "ccc"
    ]
}
```

IList and List also work.  Do you have any custom BSON serialization annotations?  Do you have custom class maps?

Comment: wow,, get result of your case is also: "_id": NumberInt(1),
   "aaa": {
     "0": "bbb",
     "1": "ccc" 
  }.
i use nuget "Install-Package mongocsharpdriver" to new console applaction

Comment: sorry. i found the crux. i use an html mongo client rockmongo, it has display problem for array.